# Dynamic Channel Switching in Hostapd

Tags: wifi

Now am working on Dynamic channel switching for access point based on interference factor in each channel. I tried with the concept they followed in ACS(automatic channel selection), but whenever i trigger the scan to get survey information from each channel i got struck( I can say my hostapd is not working ).Please give some suggestions on this.

Comment: you can provide some approaches you have tried already?

Comment: In ACS code, I made some changes to my requirement and i got the survey information. But for scanning they are changing the AP to STA mode. There am facing problem.. (hope if my analysis is correct: Once they changed STA mode its not returning back to AP mode)

Comment: Sorry guys. channel switch feature is disabled in kernel version 3.13 bcoz of synchronization problem b/w nl80211 & mac80211